# Why is the general solution to a linear 2nd order ODE in the form of $y(t)=u(t)y_1(t)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here is my attempt at justifying the claim. However, I am not sure if it's valid:
For any differential equation in the form of $y''+p(t)y'+q(t)y=f(t)$, we know that the solution is in the form of $y_h+y_p$ where $y_h$ is the general solution to $y''+p(t)y'+q(t)y= 0$.
Given that $y_1(t)$ is a solution to $y''+p(t)y'+q(t)y= 0$, we can say that $y_h(t)= C_1y_1(t)+C_2g(t)y_1(t)$ where $g(t)$ is not a scalar. Finally, we can let, $y_p(t)=h(t)y_1(t)$ for some function $h$. Thus, the general solution to $y''+p(t)y'+q(t)y=f(t)$ is $y(t) = C_1y_1(t)+C_2g(t)y_1(t)+h(t)y_1(t) = u(t)y_1(t)$ for some $u$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the context of the question. When I first looked at it I thought you were asking about the assumption at the beginning of the method of variation of parameters, but after reading the question that doesn't seem to be the case

Comment: The only reason for that to work is that $y_1$ only has isolated roots. The advantage of taking $y_1$ as factor is "reduction-of-order". That's all.

Comment: Compare with the reasoning given in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1235836/how-is-this-concluded-in-the-following-differential-equation, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3488448/why-do-we-assume-this-solution-form-in-the-method-of-variation-of-constants